# need to give margin for each grid

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

need to give margin for each grid. given below grid single view.  am using this view in each grid here i need to get 2dp margin between all grids. when i use android:layout_margin = "2dp" there occurs a problem for inner grids there will be about 4dp(2dp+2dp)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
       >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what are you using for grid? **Gridview** or **RecyclerView**

Comment: apply padding 2dp for the LinearLayout and check.

Comment: @HamidReza using gridview

Comment: @HamidReza using gridview

Comment: you can use `android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"`

Comment: @Leechippy Gridview  has options named: **horizontalSpacing** and **verticalSpacing** use them to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Gridview than normally add horizontalSpacing and verticalSpacing.

```
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/albums_gridView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
  android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
  android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
  android:numColumns="2"
  android:overScrollMode="never"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />
```

Or what are you using as parent grid view ?

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to have 2dp margin between one grid and another one and not 4dp?

What if you put `android:layout_marginTop="2dp"` at you LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

a i think i am getting it, did you try to put 1dp margin to each Content item and 1dp margin to the linear layout? so they should end up right 2dp at the outer grid and 2 at the inner